# How do I load bulk from a file excel stored in firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I am trying to load from an excel file stored in firebase that has many lines of data... my idea is to load and store them in a database... I use the ExcelJS and xlsx library but without results... the true this I part my mind... If someone has already gone through this, the explanation would help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.